# limit, differentiability

Tags: calculus

if 
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}x & x\text{ is rational}\\1-x&x\text{ is irratinal}\end{matrix}\right.$$
then which of the following is true?

a) $f\circ f(x)$ is monotonic

b) $f(x)$ + $f(1-x)$ is constant

c) $f(x)$ assumes every value between 0 and 1

d) None of the above

Comment: Please mention your attempt on the question

Comment: i got this 2nd option as f(x) +f(1-x) as 1 when x is rational and also when x is irrational but in book it is given that it is incoorect option

Answer (score 1):

(b) is indeed correct:

if $x$ is rational, then $1-x$ is rational, so $f(x)+f(1-x)=x+1-x=1$.

If $x$ is irrational, then $1-x$ is irrational, so $f(x)+f(1-x)=(1-x)+(1-(1-x))=1$

so indeed $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x)+f(1-x)=1$

(c) is also correct: $f(x)$ is a bijection $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. It assumes all values in $\mathbb{R}$, including those between 0 and 1.

Comment: this is what I thought, I drove myself crazy trying to figure out how c could be incorrect

Comment: Why is (a) not correct? Doesn't it reduce to $f(x)=x$?

Comment: and what about option a

Comment: @Muffin notice that $f\circ f={\rm id}_{\Bbb R}$, so is monotonic.

Comment: okki thanks got it